# Change HTTPs to HTTP protocol in link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have ssl configuration on `config/application.rb`

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :only => %r{^/foo/*}
```

It's work, Path with `/foo` have https protocol, but the problem is all link should use `http` protocol in `/foo` have `https` protocol, I want to change `https` protocol to `http`, I have tried with this :

```
<%= link_to "logout", logout_path, :method => :delete, :protocol => 'http' %>
## /users/sign_out
```

But link still have https protocol, also I have add ignore path in config like this

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :only => %r{^/foo/*}, ignore: [%r{^/users/sign_out}]
```

but no effect.

Comment: Have you tries adding the `:strict => true` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you want to **force** non-SSL connection for all requests not matching the constraints you set , for that you need to use the

`:strict=>true`

[Source](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer#force-redirection-to-non-ssl-connection-if-constraint-is-not-matched)